# Is $(\ln p)^\alpha$ a limit for gaps proceeding $p$ for some $\alpha$?

Tags: prime-numbers, computational-mathematics, prime-gaps

By computational experiments I found that there are no primes $p_n$ with $7<p_n<100,000,000$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n>(\ln p_n)^\alpha$, if
$\alpha\ge 1.8932$.

> Are there primes $p_n>7$ such that $p_{n+1}-p_n>(\ln p_n)^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't try to write a code for check if a "small" example exists. However, I just want to recall the [Cramer's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r's_conjecture) which states that
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\,\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{(\log p_n)^2}=1.
$$
You can find therein related references about large gaps on consecutive primes. In particular, take a look at these recent Ann. of Math. articles [here](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2016/183-3/p04) and [here](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/2016/183-3/p03).

Answer (score 1):

Not currently known.

See Nicely's discussion here: http://trnicely.net/#MaxMerit and elsewhere on his pages and publications.

The largest value of the CSG ratio $\frac{G}{\log(p1)^2}$ is 0.9206386 for G=1132 P1= 1693182318746371.

That comes out to an alpha for your formula of ~ 1.98.